# WPF как уменьшить расстояние между буквами (между Run'ами в TextBlock)?

Tags: c#, wpf, текст

Вместо "1" будут прибинжены свойства, но, очевидно, проблема остается; как можно уменьшить расстояние между этими Run'ами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Написать их в одну строку (`<Run/><Run>`), либо оставить коммент между ними (`<Run/><!--(новая_строка)--><Run/>`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо, именно то, что нужно!